# Entity name must Immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

Tags: android, string

I created String array for the List of Bank names in **string.xml** file.
When I'm using item name **State Bank of Bikaner & Jaipur** as array item:

```
 <item>State Bank of Bikaner & Jaipur</item>
```

I'm getting the following error: **`"The Entity name must Immediately follow the '&' in the entitiy reference"`**

Ideas on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `&` symbol is an entity specifier in XML. If you want to put a literal ampersand in the XML, you will need to use `&amp;`, which is the standard entity for an ampersand.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) is a list of most of the standard ones. You can also define custom entities in the DTD.

Comment: anything wrong in this url? `https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=suJrIjoiMDllZjYwZDktM2M2MS00Nzc3LWJmZDYtNjdkNjU5Yjk4OTZmIiwidCI6ImM4NDc1ZjkwLWE0ZGYtNDgzNS1iOTJiLTViNDgwZDg1MDFiYSIsImMiOjEwfQ%3D%3D` I'm getting the same exception

Answer (score 3):

The **'&'** character is itself an escape character .You should use **`&amp`** instead of **'&'** .

```
'&' --> '&amp';

'<' --> '&lt';

'>' --> '&gt';
```

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined%5Fentities%5Fin%5FXML

Comment: I think it should be `&amp;`, with a trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&amp;` instead of `&`.